# Why is this nested array not rendered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, react-hook-form

I have a problem with nested objects. I have an object where the array "information" is located and in it is another array called "financeRounds".
This is the section for the form and in it I render the financing rounds. But why are they not rendered on the second one when I call append().
Do you have any idea how to solve this?

This is my datastructure for economyData:

```
economyData:{
  information: [
    {
      financeRound: [
         {
          round: "",
          investor: ""
         }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

And this is the rest of codesandbox => https://codesandbox.io/s/array-problem-1cxx9

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your json structure, so please try

```
let temp = {economyData: {
        information: [
            {
                financeRound: [
                    {
                        round: "",
                        investor: ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
temp.economyData.information.push({financeRound:[{round:"2", investor: "who"}]});
console.log(JSON.stringify(temp));
```

The result should look like this

```
{"economyData":{"information":[{"financeRound":[{"round":"","investor":""}]}]}}
{"economyData":{"information":[{"financeRound":[{"round":"","investor":""}]},{"financeRound":[{"round":"2","investor":"who"}]}]}}
```